# Testing if a point lies on the triangle

Tags: java, geometry

I used the Polygon class to find out if a point with given points lies INSIDE a triangle, but I'm not sure how to determine whether it lies outside or ON the triangle. Here is my code so far.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c =0;
    Polygon p = new Polygon();

    p.addPoint(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
    p.addPoint(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());
    p.addPoint(s.nextInt(), s.nextInt());

    int y = 3;
    while(y-->0)
    {
    if(p.contains(s.nextDouble(),s.nextDouble()))
        c++;
    }
    System.out.print(c);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about using Line2D to represent the edges of the triangle.

```
Line2D a = new Line2D.Double();
Line2D b = new Line2D.Double();
Line2D c = new Line2D.Double();

a.setLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
b.setLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
c.setLine(x3, y3, x1, y1);

double pntX = s.nextDouble();
double pntY = s.nextDouble();

if (a.ptLineDist(pntX, pntY) == 0 || b.ptLineDist(pntX, pntY) == 0 || c.ptLineDist(pntX, pntY) == 0)
    c++;
```

Comment: I would use a delta value. Some kind of threshold. `dist < 0.0001d`

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html

According to the definition of "insideness" which Polygon uses, a point on a boundary should be considered inside, and thus contained.

Edit:

Ran some basic tests to make sure:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(1, 1);
    p.addPoint(3, 1);
    p.addPoint(2, 2);
    System.out.println(p.contains(2, 1));
    System.out.println(p.contains(2.5, 1));
    System.out.println(p.contains(2.9999, 1));
    System.out.println(p.contains(2.9999, 1.00));
}
```

All outputs were true.  I can't guarantee for you though how the class handles the int/double math inside, so you might want to test some fringe cases with double values.

Comment: you're right that's what the definition says but it doesn't seem to work for my example..:(

Comment: I actually tested it because I was curious how it would react to double data.  Seems to handle it fine, though I didn't extensively test it.  Maybe you should try typing a few by hand just to make sure the Scanner interaction is working as planned?

Comment: i think it does work, I have 4 points,(3 ,1)
(3, 2)
(3 ,3)and
(3 ,4). three of them are supposed to be inside, but my program says 2.

Comment: Hrmm, it's odd that it doesn't consider 3,3 inside of the triangle since it's one of the points.  As for why it is doing that, maybe someone more mathematically inclined than me could say.  I guess you'll have to compare the points with the points of the triangle.  Or maybe look into the other solutions offered.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to distinguish the three different cases (inside, on the edge, outside) you can always implement the test yourself:

use the barycentric technique described here http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html
formulas to use are on the bottom of that page

pseudo code for inside/outside/edge detection:

```
if 0<=u<=1 && 0<=v<=1
    // inside, maybe on edge
    if    u==0 || v==0  || u+v==1
       //edge1 || edge2 || edge3
    else
       //inside
    end
else
    //outside
end
```